# List of Menu bl_idnames? INFO_MT_file_export, etc

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, documentation

I am loosing my mind here.

Every example addon in blender uses **bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export** yet not a single doc explains where the hell the name **INFO_MT_file_export** comes from.

The doc for bpy.types doesn’t have anything about it. Which leads me to believe we are accessing some object.

I can draw the conclusion that it’s a bl_idname for the info menu and the export submenu, but I don’t understand why we can access it using the dot operator inside of bpy.types, or why we can call the append and remove function if it’s a type of Menu.

Moreover, is there a list or something of all of these predefined possible menu ids?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mousing over the base of a menu gives you the `bl_idname`.

[image]

*Note that the "Open on mouse over" option in *`Interface > Menus`* must be DISABLED or else the menu will open and the tooltip won't show. Or at least increase the delay to 1 second or so*

If you right click and select edit source it will open up the code for that space in the text editor
[image]

In this file you will find

```
class INFO_MT_file_export(Menu):
    bl_idname = "INFO_MT_file_export"
    bl_label = "Export"

    def draw(self, context):
        if bpy.app.build_options.collada:
            self.layout.operator("wm.collada_export", text="Collada (Default) (.dae)")
        if bpy.app.build_options.alembic:
            self.layout.operator("wm.alembic_export", text="Alembic (.abc)")
```

which affirms that it is a `Menu` class.  The naming convention used by blender for operators and menus is `<SPACE>_<TYPE>_<name>` where in this case it's the `INFO` space, is menu type `MT` and named `file_export`.

When a blender menu (or operator) is registered it becomes known to `bpy.types`.  If the naming convention is followed, we can find all menus in the info space, simply by using auto-complete  in the python console.

```
>>> bpy.types.INFO_MT_
                      add(
                      armature_add(
                      ...
                      file(
                      file_export(
                      file_external_data(
                      file_import(
                      file_previews(
                      ...
                      window(
```

To get a complete list of all menus, you can use python's built-in `dir()` function:

```
base_type = bpy.types.Menu
for typename in dir(bpy.types):
    bl_type = getattr(bpy.types, typename)
    if issubclass(bl_type, base_type):
        print (bl_type)
```

Comment: One last question, how come are we able to use append and remove? Those functions are present in the Menu class, or are they added by the subclass?

Comment: It's a class method of `bpy.types.Menu` and maybe not that well [documented](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Menu.html#extending-menus).   Type `bpy.types.Menu.append(` <ctrl><space> (autocomplete) into py console.

Comment: Aka, not documented at all...

Comment: Just adding for posterity: Settings->Display->Python Tooltips must be enabled to get the `bl_idname` to show up when mousing over menus.

Comment: Also note that the "Open on mouse over" option in Interface > Menus must be DISABLED or else the menu will open and the tooltip won't show. Or at least increase the delay to 1 second or so

Comment: Cheers, edited. Mouse over is my preferred option these days.