# Blender Importer/Exporter Addon updating to 2.8

Tags: export, add-on, import

I guess I need help. I have a plugin (not my code, no OSL) that was written for Blender 2.7x and was working well. It was importing and exporting certain game specific mesh formats. Now I am trying to convert that script for my personal use to Blender 2.8x.
Never been written some Blender addon at all, so my first attempt. A lot of changes I've done already and the plugin is flawlessly activating/deactivating in Preferences now, which is good.
My problem was: I was checking import/export menu (like I am used from Blender 2.7) but the addon doesn't show the options there. First I thought it was not working but I've noticed now it is in the Shift+A menu (where it adds a new type, which is working as well). But it's very unusual to have importer/exporter options in that menu? :)
Can someone point me in the right direction why it is doing that and how I can get it in the exporter menu properly?

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of existing import/export add-ons, e.g. for [.obj](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_obj/__init__.py). You likely want to use `ImportHelper` or `ExportHelper` for your operator.

Comment: I was googling for ImportHelper before but found only entries about having it a filebrowser function.

Comment: The plugin is working now, but the import/export entries are still in the Shift+A menu, still working from there. I don't see a way how ImportHelper could help me to get the entries to the import/export sub menues?

Comment: It would help if you could add your code to the question. Otherwise I would have to guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Agree please always, if you have it, post code.  When editing Q could be more appropriately titled _"Why is my Addon  appending item to Add Object Menu not Import / Export Menu"_  It is courteous to add a link , if code is sourced from elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

and to answer my own question, finally I found it via Texteditor.
The needed command is TOPBAR_MT_file_import e.g.
bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)

Comment: Right, I thought that was obvious from my link to the .obj add-on. I'm sorry if that wasn't the case.

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the _"needed command"_  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110095/list-of-menu-bl-idnames-info-mt-file-export-etc